# Backbonejs: model not getting passed in underscore template

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new to backbonejs. What I am trying to do is, render a template on page load and pass model as data parameter in `_.template` function. Here is my bacbone code:

```
var Trip = Backbone.Model.extend({
      url: '/trips/' + trip_id + '/show'
    });  

    var InviteTraveller = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',

      render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var trip = new Trip();
        trip.fetch({
            success: function(){
              console.log(trip); //logs trip object correctly
              var template = _.template($('#invite-traveller-template').html(), {trip: trip});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
          });       
        }
      });

      var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          '': 'fetchTrip'
        }
      }); 

      var inviteTraveller = new InviteTraveller();

      var router = new Router();

      router.on('route:fetchTrip',function () {
        inviteTraveller.render();
      });

      Backbone.history.start();
```

And here is my sample template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="invite-traveller-template">
      <h3>Trip</h3>
      <h3><%= trip.get('name') %></h3>
</script>
```

On running, I am getting the [this](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Screenshot%20from%202014-02-13%2010:42:52.png?_subject_uid=176857415&w=AACY7pslRKaAIQMhFDe--7oOgS34L8WbVQWWOa_arB3_2Q) in browser window and console shows:

```
trip is not defined
```

I am facing this issue since yesterday but could not figure out the solution yet. Not understanding what is going wrong, code also seems to be right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I removed

```
inviteTravellers.render();
```

from `router.on()` and then reloaded the page in browser. I still got same error which means that `<script></script>` (template) is being compiled before calling `render()` of `InviteTraveller` view. What can be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code seems to be right but still my template was getting compiled on page load and I was getting `trip is not defined` error. I did not understand the reason of this behavior yet.

I solved this issue by using [`handlebarsjs`](http://handlebarsjs.com/) instead  of default underscore templates.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (underscore v1.8.2).  My fix:

```
var template = _.template($('#invite-traveller-template').html());
var compiled = template({trip: trip});
that.$el.html(compiled);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the whole model to the template. Typically you would call [model.toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) and then pass its result to the template. Additionally using `<%=` in your template to render the attribute, which is meant for [interpolating variables](http://underscorejs.org/#template) from that JSON object you're passing.

You *can* pass a whole model to the template and use `<% ... %>` to execute pure Javascript code and use `print` to get the attribute but it's probably overkill.

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rky6S/1/).

Comment: I tried calling `toJSON()` on `trip` model and then in template `<%= name%>`. Now I am getting `name is not defined` in console. Something is going wrong, the data is not getting passed to the template.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the success function and inspect the `trip` variable.

Comment: I think you're having scope issues and `trip` is not defined correctly. You can try adding `(model, response, options)` to the function signature as per [the model.fetch doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) and use `model` to instead of `trip`.

Comment: changing the signature of `success` callback and using `model` instead of `trip` also did not work :( I am getting the data in success callback but I am not being able to access it in template.

Comment: I noticed something. Even after removing `inviteTraveller.render();` from `router.on`, I am getting `trip is not defined` error which means that `<script></script>` is being compiled on page load which should not happen I guess.

Comment: Having `type="text/template"` prevents the browser from executing any code inside the tag, it will be interpreted as text. Place a breakpoint in the render function and look at the stack, something else must be calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You code work perfectfly, [here's it](http://jsfiddle.net/PpDwq/)

I think that your problem came from another code, not the one you have posted, because there's no way for your view to render if you remove :

```
inviteTravellers.render();
```

---

Try to chaneg `<h3><% trip.get('name'); %></h3>` by `<h3><%= trip.get('name') %></h3>`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still getting that error which means my script is being compiled before `render()` being called.

Comment: maybe your utilities.js that cause the problem ?

Comment: No. It is not doing anything related to backbone.